# Mime type for custom data in tree view

Tags: qt, qt5

The items in the tree view hold a instance of class container.
I want to implement drag and drop functionality in the view.

According to the QT tutorial for the data to copy i need specify the mime type and than write the Mimedata and dropMimeData functions.

The QT Example is  dealing with a simple string so i am totally clueless of how to implement these function in case of custom objects.

1) What should be the mime type in my case ?

2) How to implement the current mimedata function for Container object data?

3) How to implement the current dropmimedata function for Container object data?

```
 /////////////////////////////////////////
 class Container
   {
   private:
    std::string stdstrContainerName;
    std::string stdstrPluginType;
    int iSegments;
    float fRadius;

   public:
     Container();
     Container(std::string , std::string ,  int , float);
     Container(const  Container& obj);  
    ~Container();
    std::string GetName();
    std::string GetType();
    void SetName(std::string stdstrName);
   };
  Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( Container )

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  QMimeData *DragDropListModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) 
  const
  {
     QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData();
     QByteArray encodedData;

      QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

     foreach (const QModelIndex &index, indexes) {
         if (index.isValid()) {
            QString text = data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            // I have a GetContainer function which returns the Container 
            //object and i can use the GetContainer instead of data function.
            stream << text;
        }
     }

     mimeData->setData("application/vnd.text.list", encodedData);
     return mimeData;
   }
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    bool DragDropListModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data,
    Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex 
      &parent)
    {
       if (action == Qt::IgnoreAction)
         return true;

       if (!data->hasFormat("application/vnd.text.list"))
          return false;

       if (column > 0)
          return false;

int beginRow;

if (row != -1)
    beginRow = row;

else if (parent.isValid())
    beginRow = parent.row();
else
    beginRow = rowCount(QModelIndex()); 


   QByteArray encodedData = data->data("application/vnd.text.list");
   QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
   QStringList newItems;
   int rows = 0;

    while (!stream.atEnd()) {
       QString text;
       stream >> text;
       newItems << text;
       ++rows;
    }

     insertRows(beginRow, rows, QModelIndex());
     foreach (const QString &text, newItems) {
       QModelIndex idx = index(beginRow, 0, QModelIndex());
      setData(idx, text);
      beginRow++;
      }

   return true;
}
```

The header file for TreeItem.

```
class TreeItem
{
 public:
   explicit TreeItem( const Container &data , TreeItem *parent = 0 );
 ~TreeItem();
 TreeItem *parent();
 void appendChild(TreeItem *child);

 TreeItem *child(int iNumber);
 int childCount() const;
 int childNumber() const;
 Container data() const;
 bool setData(const Container &data , QVariant value);
 void setContainer(const Container &data);
 bool insertChildren(int position, int count );
 bool removeChildren( int position  , int count );

 private:
    QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
    Container itemData;
    TreeItem* parentItem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add your custom mime types to specify the type of container you want to drag/drop. See this [post](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html#adding-new-drag-and-drop-types) for details.

> The QDrag object constructed by the source contains a list of MIME types that it uses to represent the data (ordered from most appropriate to least appropriate), and the drop target uses one of these to access the data.

First of all, try to find a compatible standard mime type. Those are the most common one assigned by the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

If the one you are looking for is not in the list, then you can label your custom one and serialize your data into a `QByteArray` to share it.

```
QByteArray output;
// do whatever
mimeData->setData("my-awesome-mime-type", output);
```

Now, in your custom widget, don't forget to accept  the drops of this mime type:

```
void Window::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)  {
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("my-awesome-mime-type"))
        event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

You can find a complete example in this [project](https://github.com/francescmm/SmallPillsOfQt).